# How to ignore tag inside RegExp

Tags: javascript, html, regex

In my project, we use a RegExp to display the title of cards that we receive from the deck.
And recently I found that from the deck side we sometimes receive different formats and the titles didn't display.

So, before it was always a string like this:

```
const res =
  `<p class="cardTitle" style="font-size: 27.2px">
    <span>Some text here</span><span> - Title</span>
   </p>`;
```

and the RegExp was:

```
/<p class="cardTitle"[^>]*>[\s]*<span[^>]*>(.+)<\/span><span[^>]*>(.+)<\/span><div[^>]*>(.+)<\/div>+[\s]*<\/p>/i.exec(res);
```

Now sometimes we receive `res` with `div` and `<br>` tags inside

```
const res = 
  `<p class="cardTitle" style="font-size: 27.2px">
    <span>Some text here</span><span> - Title</span>
    <div style="font-size: 10px">Title:<br>Some text here</div>
   </p>`;
```

The question is, how to change the RegEx to ignore this `<div>..<br>.</div>`?

Here's a demo:

```js
const res =
  `<p class="cardTitle" style="font-size: 27.2px">
    <span>Some text here</span><span> - Title</span>
   </p>`;
   
const newRes =
  `<p class="cardTitle" style="font-size: 27.2px">
    <span>Some text here</span><span> - Title</span>
    <div style="font-size: 10px">Title:<br>Some text here</div>
   </p>`;
   
const regEx = /<p class="cardTitle"[^>]*>[\s]*<span[^>]*>(.+)<\/span><span[^>]*>(.+)<\/span>+[\s]*<\/p>/i;
   
const correct = regEx.exec(res);
const broken = regEx.exec(newRes);
 
console.log('correct', correct);
console.log('broken', broken);
```

Would be really grateful for any help!

Comment: Dont try to use regex, parse it using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and use dom methods to extract what you want or remove what you dont

Comment: Possible [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify the regex

```
/<p class="cardTitle"[^>]*>\s*<span[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span><span[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span>.*?<\/p>/si
```

This will get the `p` tag, with the 2 spans and whatever else it contains.

```js
const res =
  `<p class="cardTitle" style="font-size: 27.2px">
    <span>Some text here</span><span> - Title</span>
   </p>`;
   
const newRes =
  `<p class="cardTitle" style="font-size: 27.2px">
    <span>Some text here</span><span> - Title</span>
    <div style="font-size: 10px">Title:<br>Some text here</div>
   </p>`;
   
const regEx = /<p class="cardTitle"[^>]*>\s*<span[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span><span[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span>.*?<\/p>/si;
   
const correct = regEx.exec(res);
const broken = regEx.exec(newRes);
 
console.log('correct', correct);
console.log('broken', broken);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the htmlString into the DOM, then extract the text.

```js
const res =
  `<p class="cardTitle" style="font-size: 27.2px">
    <span>Some text here</span><span> - Title</span>
    <div style="font-size: 10px">Title:<br>Some text here</div>
   </p>`;
const getNodes = str => {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', str);
  const DOM = document.querySelector('.cardTitle');
  return DOM.innerText;
};

console.log(getNodes(res));
```